# How to access Google Docs using Python

Tags: python, google-docs-api

For Google Spread Sheet, gsperad is a great tool to access, modify and retrieve Google SpreadSheet.

Is there a tool for Google Docs, to access and modify Googel Docs document in Python?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Google has a Google Doc API for use with Python. Please refer to the following links for more information:

1. [Drive API Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/drive/v2)
2. [Quickstart: Run a Drive App in Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-python)